# Assigning value to returned shared_ptr doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a private three dimensional vector of `shared_ptr<Room>` objects as follows:

```
private:
    vector<vector<vector<shared_ptr<Room>>>> world;
```

In the same class, I provide access to `Room` objects:

```
public:
    shared_ptr<Room> room_at(const int & x, const int & y, const int & z) const
    {
        return world.at(x).at(y).at(z);
    }
```

Also in the same class, I initialize the `world` structure:

```
for (int x = 0; x < C::WORLD_X_DIMENSION; ++x)
{
    vector<vector<shared_ptr<Room>>> row;
    for (int y = 0; y < C::WORLD_Y_DIMENSION; ++y)
    {
        vector<shared_ptr<Room>> vertical_stack; // "stack"
        for (int z = 0; z < C::WORLD_Z_DIMENSION; ++z)
        {
            vertical_stack.push_back(shared_ptr<Room>(nullptr));
        }
        row.push_back(vertical_stack);
    }
    world.push_back(row);
}
```

Later, I want to save a `Room` object into `world`:

```
void add_room_to_world(const int & x, const int & y, const int & z)
{
    shared_ptr<Room> room = make_shared<Room>(); // create an empty room

    /* (populate room's member fields) */

    // add room to world
    room_at(x, y, z) = room; // This doesn't work as expected
}
```

The `shared_ptr` within `world` starts out as `nullptr` as expected, but doesn't change on the last line above.

Based on what I've found on SO, I've tried `operator=` (above), `.reset(room)`, and `make_shared<Room>(room)` (using an actual `Room` object rather than `shared_ptr<Room>`) but in all cases, the `shared_ptr` within `world` stays set to `nullptr`.

What is the correct way to assign objects into `world`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`room_at` returns a value. When it is returned from the function it is copied, so any operations that you do on the returned value don't affect the original value. If you want to change the original value you have to return a reference like this:

```
shared_ptr<Room>& room_at(const int & x, const int & y, const int & z) const
{
   return world.at(x).at(y).at(z);
}
```

If you don't want users of your class to be able to do this, declare this method private and keep the original as it is.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. I overloaded the method using your code to allow mutable and non-mutable access.

Answer (score 3):

`room_at` returns a value. When you mutate this value, who cares? You're just mutating some random temporary. It has no meaning to the object it was copied from.

To support what you want, `room_at` would need to return a mutable reference- a very bad idea for a public API in this fashion.

You would want to offer an analagous private method that returns the mutable reference, and then implement `room_at` as just returning a copy of the object referenced by that function.